# indexPathForItemAtPoint with custom cell frame

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating collection view. I change the cell's size and position in the CollectionViewController:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath 
indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(
reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
```

and then change `cell.frame` for each individual item

```
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(x , y, width, height)
```

This all works fine but when using a gesture recognizer, I want to identify the cells using `collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint()`.

`collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint()`, does not recognize the changes I made to the cells' sizes and positions and returns nil. It only works when I drag from the (invisible) original positions. I have found solutions that include going through all cells manually, but I am still wondering if it is possible to change the cells' position and size in a way that `collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint()` would recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this is because `UICollectionView` doesn't use the actual view hierarchy to answer the question you're asking.  `UICollectionView` has a layout object, appropriately named [`UICollectionViewLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html).  The default layout object is `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.  When you ask for a cell at a point, it's using the info provided by the layout object.

Here's the important bit: if you want to position cells differently than what Flow Layout does, you need to subclass it or the base class and implement your own layout methods.  Alternatively, you may be able to get the default Flow Layout object in sync with your changes.  I'm not sure.

It's not trivial, and I don't have a simple out of the box solution for what you want.  You'll have to work through it and ask specific questions as you go.  [Here](https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout) is an example that subclasses Flow Layout to allow reordering which may be helpful for you to look at.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that!